# how to fix this MySQL code it displays an error

Tags: sql, mysql

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS basic_DB;
create table if not exists basic_DB.users
(
    id serial primary key,
    login varchar(50) not null unique,
    password varchar(100) not null
    );


create table  if not exists basic_DB.files
(
    id serial primary key,
    file_name varchar(50),
    type varchar(10) not null ,
    content BLOB not null,
    create_date timestamp,
    size bigint not null,
    user_id serial,
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_files FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES basic_DB.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    );
```

> [2024-03-29 14:46:17] [42000][1075] Incorrect table definition; there
> can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

I tried to convert user_id to integer,
but after that another error came out

```
create table  if not exists basic_DB.files
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    file_name varchar(50),
    type varchar(10) not null ,
    content BLOB not null,
    create_date timestamp,
    size bigint not null,
    user_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_files FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES basic_DB.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
);
```

> [2024-03-29 14:33:04] [HY000][3780] Referencing column 'user_id' and
> referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'fk_users_files' are
> incompatible.